# Can I change the Locale in MS Word System Information

Tags: microsoft-word, language

When I go to tools then to About MS Word then to System Information it show my Locale as Zimbabwe. Can I change this to USA?

As it is, every time I type a document I have to change the language to US from Zimbabwe.

Answer (score 2):

You can change your language by going to (in 2007/2010) the review tab > Language. From there you can set your language preferences. In Word XP/2003 you can change this setting under the Microsoft Office tools.

Comment: How to do that in a per document basis?